# I'm trying to make a php Curl call to formstack api, but I get nothing

Tags: php, api, curl, formstack

This is one of my first curls code, so it can have mistakes

I'm trying to be able to make calls to form/:id/submissions
https://www.formstack.com/developers/api/resources/submission#form/:id/submission_GET

If I load:

> https://www.formstack.com/api/v2/form/1311091/submission.json?oauth_token=abc&min_time=2012-09-01%2000:01:01&max_time=2012-10-27%2000:01:01

If works great.

If I try this code:

```
 <?php    
 $host = 'https://www.formstack.com/api/v2/';

  // TODO this should manage dinamics values or build an action in every method. 
  $action = 'form/1311091/submission.json';

  $url = $host . $action;

  // TODO this values will arrive like an array with values
    $postData['oauth_token']= 'abc';
    $postData['min_time'] ='2012-09-01 00:01:01';
    $postData['max_time'] ='2012-10-27 00:01:01';

// TODO make a method with this action
function getElements($postData)
{

    $elements = array();  
    foreach ($postData as $name=>$value) {  
       $elements[] = "{$name}=".urlencode($value);  
    } 
}


  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $elements);
  $result =  curl_exec($curl) ;
  curl_close($curl);
  var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: Formstack developer here. Don't put your access_token in public places!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

As an option before curl_exec() if you wish to get data back.

> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the
>   return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Also, why are you trying to send POST data via a GET request?

> CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS: The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation.

Also, for debugging, you should check out:

```
echo curl_error ( $curl );
```

Comment: Thanks Wayne. I use Postfields because of the information after the "?", I thought this options should be through the Postfields. 
I have to give all the elements in the url?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<?php
$host = 'https://www.formstack.com/api/v2/';
$action = 'form/1311091/submission.json';

$url = $host . $action;

$postData = array();
$postData['oauth_token']= 'REPLACE_WITH_TOKEN';
$postData['min_time'] ='2012-09-01 00:01:01';
$postData['max_time'] ='2012-10-27 00:01:01';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$result =  curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I get this message:

{"id":"84948981","message":"

The form was submitted successfully.<\/p>","timestamp":"2012-10-26 10:52:44","user_agent":"","remote_addr":"91.121.16.103","payment_status":"","form":"1311091","data":[],"pretty_field_id":"17286794"}bool(true)


I copy/paste your code.